# Deriving the lever law using infinitesimals

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

I'm trying to derive the lever law by myself, however, I'm stuck. Please follow the logic of my calculations.

[image]

Every object in the picture has the same mass. I want to prove that, under the effect of the gravitational force, I can replace the objects in A and C with the two objects in B, and obtain a system that behaves in the same way.

Since the same gravitational force acts in the objects, in an infinitesimal time interval $dt$ they all get the same $dv$. However, the correspondent infinitesimal change in angular velocity also depends on the distance between the object(s) and the fulcrum.
If i prove that in an $dt$ the $d\omega$ due to the objects in A and C is equal to the $d\omega$ due to the two objects on B, i'm done.

$d\omega_{A}+d\omega_{C}=d\omega_{B}$

that is

$\frac{dv}{OA}+\frac{dv}{OA+D}=\frac{2dv}{OA+\frac{D}{2}}$
where O is the fulcrum and D is the distance between C and A.

However, doing some calculations i found that...

$\frac{dv}{OA}+\frac{dv}{OA+D}\neq\frac{2dv}{OA+\frac{D}{2}}$

Comment: Of course it is $\frac{1}{OA}+\frac{1}{OA+D}\neq\frac{2}{OA+\frac{D}{2}}$.
So you have correctly proven that two single masses in A and C have *not* the same effect as a double mass in B.

Comment: Mhm, I thought that B was the center of gravity of A and C, and that replacing the objects in A and C with the two objects in B  would have produced the same effect... Where am I wrong?

Comment: Then why the author says that the 6 blocks highlighted in grey have the same effect as a single block in A? Can you explain to me more deeply?